# Automating Eclipse project configuration

Tags: eclipse

I keep my **.project** and **.classpath** files in my source repository. I maintain separate eclipse workspaces for each branch off my trunk. I've found the best way to do this is to recursively copy my trunk workspace (**cp -r dev/ branch-foo/**). This works great. There are a few other details that facilitate sharing templates and key mappings, but that's not important here. The issue with this solution is that I end up with a workspace that, to no surprise, contains all the trunk projects. I then have to remove all these projects from the workspace manually and then import all the projects in the branch. Not a huge deal, but I'm wondering if something better can be done to automate this process.

I don't see any files that get written to as I add/remove project files in my workspace so I'm assuming eclipse manages these relationships in some internal DB or something. Additionally, I looked into any command-line support eclipse offers for doing this, but don't see anything.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

One P.S. - I do see some binary files located in **~/workspace/branch/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/project_name/**

Comment: Which SCM do you use? Any answer depends on this :-)

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with Perforce...